# Aftersubmit event in Trirand jqgrid Commercial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvcjqgrid

Can someone tell me how to use AfterSubmit Event in Commercial jqgrid for ASP.Net MVC? Im not able to find enough documentation for commercial JQGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by defining the ClientSideEvents - on the server side.

```
  chargesJQGrid.ClientSideEvents.AfterAddDialogRowInserted = "AfterInsert";
  chargesJQGrid.ClientSideEvents.AfterDeleteDialogRowDeleted = "AfterDelete";
```

Then implemented the javascript method

```
function AfterInsert(response,postdata) 
 {
 }

 function AfterDelete(response,postdata) 
  {  
  }
```